# MVC cannot use any other function than Find and FindOneBy

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql, model-view-controller, php-pgsql

I have a project to do in PHP (MVC) with my university. Unfortunately, I've been stuck for a week, and nobody in the university knows where the problem is.

**Error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Undefined method
> 'persist'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!
> in
> /nfs/data01/data/uapv19/uapv1948/public_html/squelette_L3/lib/core/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php:226
> Stack trace: #0
> /nfs/data01/data/uapv19/uapv1948/public_html/squelette_L3/Cericar/model/utilisateurTable.class.php(40):
> Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->__call('persist', Array) #1
> /nfs/data01/data/uapv19/uapv1948/public_html/squelette_L3/Cericar/controller/mainController.php(58):
> utilisateurTable::registerUser('3', 'Id123', 'mdp123', 'Bye', 'ByeB')
> #2 /nfs/data01/data/uapv19/uapv1948/public_html/squelette_L3/lib/core/context.class.php(52):
> mainController::testinscription(Array, Object(context)) #3
> /nfs/data01/data/uapv19/uapv1948/public_html/squelette_L3/CericarAjax.php(22):
> context->executeAction('testinscription', Array) #4  {main} thrown in
> /nfs/data01/data/uapv19/uapv1948/public_html/squelette_L3/lib/core/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php on line 226

When I try to use 'persist' or 'execute' or 'flush' I have the same error above.

```
// Inclusion de la classe utilisateur
require_once "utilisateur.class.php";

class utilisateurTable
{
    public static function getUserByLoginAndPass($login, $pass)
    {
        $em = dbconnection::getInstance()->getEntityManager();
        $userRepository = $em->getRepository('utilisateur');
        $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(array('identifiable => $login, 'pass' => sha1($pass)));
        if ($user == false) {
            echo 'Erreur SQL;
        }
        
        return $user;
    }

    public static function getUserById($id)
    {
        $em = dbconnection::getInstance()->getEntityManager();
        $userRepository = $em->getRepository('utilisateur');
        $user = $userRepository->findBy(array('id' => $id));
        if ($user == false) {
            echo 'Erreur SQL;
        }
        
        return $true;
    }

    public static function registerUser($id, $identifiant, $pass, $nom, $prenom)
    {
        $em = dbconnection::getInstance()->getEntityManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('utilisateur');
        $user1 = new utilisateur;
        $user1->id = $id;
        $user1->identifiant = $identifiant;
        $user1->password = $pass;
        $user1->nom = $nom;
        $user1->prenom = $prenom;
        $user->persist($user1);
        $user->flush();
        
        return true;
    }
 }
```

**Class**

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class utilisateur
{
    public $id;
    public $identifiant;
    public $pass;
    public $nom;
    public $prenom;
    public $avatar;
}
```

**Controller**

```
class mainController
{
    public static function testinscription($request, $context)
    {
        $context->id = $_POST['id'];
        $context->identifiant = $_POST['identifiant'];
        $context->password = $_POST['password'];
        $context->nom = $_POST['nom'];
        $context->prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
        $context->utilisateur = utilisateurTable::registerUser($context->id, 
            $context->identifiant, $context->password,
            $context->nom, $context->prenom);

        return context::SUCCESS;
    }

    public static function FormInscription($request, $context)
    {
        return context::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

So I tried different things to solve my problem, but even my colleague did not know where the problem was. So if you want any other file, ask.

Comment: Seems like there is no method persist on `$user`. Try `dd($user);` before calling persist to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I'm not very good at php but do I need to put a link because they say to me Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dd()

Comment: My bad. Try with `var_dump($user); die;`

Comment: 55000 character display in front of me to be honest I don't understand any of this !